Dapper how to pass object with list of objects into stored procedure
I have a problem with executing an existing stored procedure using Dapper. The stored procedure takes some parameters and list of user-defined type object. I mimicked the required parameters in C#, but some conversion doesn't go well, that causes an exception(listed below) and I can't figure out how to solve it.
SQL Server stored procedure:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySp]
    @Name VARCHAR(60),
    @Size BIGINT,
    @Photos MyPhoto READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- ... logic

where MyPhoto is a user-defined table type with:
Name VARCHAR(25),
Model VARCHAR(25)

On the C# side, I have:
public class MyClassForSP
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int64 Size { get; set; }
    public List<Photos> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Photos
{
    public string Name { get; set }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

So far everything looks logical for me... so I tried to execute a SQL request:
public void ExecuteSp(MyClassForSP classForSp)
{
    using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_settings.ConnectionString);

    var result = await connection.QuerySingleAsync<MyResult>("dbo.MySp", classForSp, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}

As result I get a Dapper error:

System.NotSupportedException: 'The member of type MyNameSpace.Photos cannot be used as a parameter value'


This might help - Dapper Table-Valued Parameter. Essentially you can't pass an enumerable directly and expect implicit translation to your TVP, you first have to create a datatable in the right format, then pass this as a parameter using DataTable.AsTableValuedParameter()

You need to use Table-Valued Parameter by providing the DataTable.
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Model");

foreach (var photo in classForSp.Photos) 
{
    dt.Rows.Add(photo.Name, photo.Model);
}

using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_settings.ConnectionString);
var result = await connection.QuerySingleAsync<MyResult>("dbo.MySp", 
    new 
    { 
        Name = classForSp.Name, 
        Size = classForSp.Size, 
        Photos = dt.AsTableValuedParameter("MyPhoto") 
    }, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

If you are looking for a generic way to convert the list into DataTable for Table-Valued parameter, you can implement an extension method as below:
public static class IListExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
            dataTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);

        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
                row[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
}

Caller:
DataTable dt = classForSp.Photos.ToDataTable();


It works, but do we have any nicer ways to convert the data class into paramerts without extra typing of the same parameter names?

Hi, from my understanding you want to convert the data class into DataTable in generic way? If yes, I add my answer on writing an extension method to convert to DataTable. Demo
